# Interpreting a function notation for Fourier transform

Tags: functions

The function was given in a notation which I am fairly new to, whereby it had $f(x) =$ { (big version of this not sure how to do it LaTeX) then explanations of the function in 2 or 3 separate lines containing a number and also $x\ge$ something or the like. I'm assuming the notation means the function is "something" when $x\ge$something, if I'm correct then my function is

$f(x) =  1$ when $|x|\le1$

$f(x) =  0$ when $|x|\ge1$

Then when plugging in to the Fourier transform do we have

$\int_{-1}^11e^{ikx}$dx for example for the first part

Sorry about the confusing explanation but now sure how better to put it, also if anyone can edit the LaTeX part of a big ${$ then it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & |x| \leq 1\\
0 & |x| > 1?
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Beware that you specified two different values when $|x|=1$, so that $f$ is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I just use $F$ or $\hat{f}$ to denote the Fourier transform, but the inegral should be:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^11e^{-ikx}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

This notation can be called a piecewise definition (specifically, piecewise constant). It is used when you need different analytical expressions on different parts of the domain.

For the LaTeX syntax, have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aDisplaying_a_formula#Continuation_and_cases).